# I can't insert data from dropdown html into sql

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi i'm a student and try to practicing on the website and get  some error.
I can't insert data that fetch from sql to dropdown html box into my sql.

I have already tried to give name to form action.
The error said Undefined Index

This is  the code below

Choose Result Mixture:

```
    <form action="insert_formula.php" method="post" name="mixture_name">
       <select name="mixture_name" input type=" text">
       <?php
         echo "<option value=mixture>" . "Select Mixture" . "</option>";
         $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from MixtureInformation");
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) 
         {?>
            <option><?php echo $row["mixture_name"]; ?></option>
   <?php }?>
       </select>
    </form>
```

And I cant input this type action into sql here is the insert_formula.php

Comment: $MixtureResult = $_POST['mixture_name'];

Comment: What error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, remove input type from select tag and also check your connection is correct , Try to print query result

```
    <form action="insert_formula.php" method="post" name="mixture_name">
         <select name="mixture_name">
             <?php
             //$link=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","yourdb");
             //check your dbconnection is correct
             $res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from MixtureInformation");
             //print_r($res);
             echo "<option value=mixture>" . "Select Mixture" . "</option>";
             while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
                ?>
                <option value="your_value"><?php echo $row["mixture_name"]; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$MixtureResult = $_POST['mixture_name'];

mysqli_select_db($conn, 'Testing');
```

$sql = "INSERT INTO Formula(first_substance_name,second_substance_name,third_substance_name,mixture_name,formula_name,formula_number,formula_info,research_ID) 
VALUES (' $FirstSub',' $SecondSub',' $ThirdSub',' $MixtureResult',' $Formula_Name',' $Formula_Number',' $Formula_Information',' $Research_Number');";